# Как использовать готовую БД в приложении под Android?

Tags: java, android, база-данных

Я новичок в разработке под Android. Нашел много информации в интернете о том как создавать базы данных, управлять, вносить какие либо изменения, но мне нужно создать базу данных отдельно, и поставлять ее уже созданную со своим приложением, то есть она должна быть как-то упакована в apk. При этом все должно происходить без подключения к интернету.

Можно ли вообще сделать это ? Если да, то как это лучше реализовать?

Comment: Задача тривиальная. Вот здесь все очень подробно рассказано [прочитай здесь](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite.html) и [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/125883/)

Comment: Советую бурить инет дальше, а то Вы быстро сдались

Comment: @iFr0z ++ на самом деле была инфа когда увидел было поздно

Comment: Вот еще то что сам [нашел](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/sqlite/readydb.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать базу, положить ее в `assets`, при запуске проверить и скопировать базу если не найдена. `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, int version) throws IOException {
            super(context, name, null, version);

            File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(name);

            if (!dbFile.exists()) {
                dbFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(name);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer);
                }

                os.flush();
                os.close();
                is.close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }
```